# Format date in AngularJS is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my project the data is coming to front-end as a json object as shown below:

```
{
  id: 1,
  meetingName: "Meeting 1",
  meetingDate: "2018-02-21",
  startTime: "10:00:00"
}
```

`<td>{{meeting.startTime|date:"h:mma"}}</td>`

I used the above method to format the date in angularjs code as 10:00 AM.
But the start time is still shown as `10:00:00`. Why is it not formatting the date according to the format?

Comment: it's a `string` and not a `Date` object

Comment: because the startTime you are getting in response is in string format and not in date format.

Comment: Try to convert your string date into long format. Then use a date filter.

Comment: Yes it has happened since the start time is not a `Data` object. it should be a format of `Date` object (eg: startTime: "2018-03-05T10:22:24.361Z") to format using angularjs date formats. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`date` filter expects a date object as input. But you are passing a string. Below is a sample code that show the date as expected.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
  let info = {
    id: 1,
    meetingName: "Meeting 1",
    meetingDate: "2018-02-21",
    startTime: "10:00:00"
  }
  $scope.meetingDate= new Date(info.meetingDate + " " + info.startTime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

    <p>Meeting Time= {{ meetingDate | date:"h:mma" }}</p>

  </div>

</body>
```

[Date Filter Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Filter `date` expects an object of type [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). This custom filter could help you:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{data.startTime|timeFilter: data.meetingDate: 'h:mma'}}
  {{data.startTime|timeFilter: data.meetingDate: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    id: 1,
    meetingName: "Meeting 1",
    meetingDate: "2018-02-21",
    startTime: "10:00:00"
  };
});

myApp.filter('timeFilter', function ($filter) {
  return function (data, aDate, dateFilter) {
    return $filter('date')(new Date(aDate + " " + data), dateFilter);
  }
})
```

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3665kg39/)**